# Incrementation not showing in MessageBox and variable values being changed

Tags: c#, operators, increment

I have two questions about this code...

1. Why is that at line 10 it starts keeping the current value. For example,

   ```
   int a = 7
   ```

   `(a += 4)` Which is `11` is brought over to the next line of code `(a -= 4)` now making it `7`. Instead of just using it initial declaration for the variable `a` which is `7`. How come I don't get `3` ? Is the `=` in the `+=` operator changing what I initially declared it in the beginning of the code ? Does `a` still hold the value `7` in memory, or does those statements change that?
2. At the last `MessageBox.Show()` statement. I increment `a` by `1` using `a++`. However, I get the same value I had for the previous `MessageBox.Show()`. How come it didn't increment ??

This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 7;
    int b = 3;

    MessageBox.Show((a + b).ToString(), "a+b");
    MessageBox.Show((a - b).ToString(), "a-b");
    MessageBox.Show((a * b).ToString(), "a*b");
    MessageBox.Show((a / b).ToString(), "a/b");
    MessageBox.Show((a += 4).ToString(), "a+=4"); //adds 4 to a
    MessageBox.Show((a -= 4).ToString(), "a-=4"); //substracts 4 from a
    MessageBox.Show((a *= 4).ToString(), "a*=4"); //multiplies 4 from a
    MessageBox.Show(a++.ToString(), "a++"); //adds 1 to a
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at the docs for the operators you're using to understand what they're doing. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reference link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How come I don't get 3 ? Is the "=" in the "+=" operator changing what
>   I initially declared it in the beginning of the code ?

The `+=` operator is equivalent to:

```
a = a + 4
```

Effectively assigning a new value to `a`.

> Does "a" still hold the value 7 in memory, or does those statements
>   change that?

It doesn't. After your first assignment, it changes.

> At the last MessageBox.Show() statement. I increment "a" by 1 using
>   "a++". However, I get the same value I had for the previous
>   MessageBox.Show(). How come it didn't increment ??

That's what happens when you use `++` as a postfix. [The docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx):

> The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is **the value of the operand before it has been incremented.**

But, if you use it as a prefix:

```
MessageBox.Show((++a).ToString(), "++a");
```

You'll see the updated value, again as the docs say:

> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is **the value of the operand after it has been incremented.**

Comment: This doesn't compile MessageBox.Show(++a.ToString(), "++a"); it should be MessageBox.Show((++a).ToString(), "++a"); :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 MessageBox.Show((a += 4).ToString(), "a+=4"); //adds 4 to a
```

This sentance result is 7+4=11 so in a it takes 11 value
after that

```
MessageBox.Show((a -= 4).ToString(), "a-=4"); //substracts 4 from a
```

for this sentance it take a value i.e current value it 11
i.e 11-4=7 so a value now is 7;

```
MessageBox.Show(a++.ToString(), "a++"); //adds 1 to a
```

in this it post-increment condition so in this it use that value and for next loop it increment by 1 
For Above condition you can use

`MessageBox.Show((++a).ToString(), "a++"); //adds 1 to a`

```
MessageBox.Show((a *= 4).ToString(), "a*=4"); //multiplies 4 from a
```

and for this also it take 7
and `+=` mean

```
a=a+b;
```

for post incerement and pre incerement condition go through this [What is the difference between pre increment and post increment operator](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-operator-in-C++)

Answer (score 2):

(a += 4) increments the value of a by 4 and returns the incremented value.

a++ increments the value of a by 1 but still returns the original value.

++a increments the value of a by 1 and returns the incremented value.

try to add this line and you will notice it:

```
MessageBox.Show((++a).ToString(), "a++");
```